# WORDPRESS CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting the following problem on a site I'm developing:

Access to font at 'http://localhost/smartskills/wp-content/themes/smart_skills_theme/template_helpers/icons/kl-social-icons/kl-social-icons.woff' from origin 'http://smartskills.tn' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
http://smartskills.tn/site/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

Comment: you font is referring localhost path. please replace with live site url

Comment: check this css http://smartskills.tn/site/wp-content/uploads/zn_dynamic.css?ver=1531211005.9117

Comment: sorry but nothing works

Comment: replace all `//localhost/smartskills` to your site ur in this files `smartskills.tn/site/wp-content/uploads/zn_dynamic.css?ver=1531211005.9117`

Comment: clear the cache and check. Seems its working fine

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Replace all //localhost/smartskills to your site ur in this files smartskills.tn/site/wp-content/uploads/zn_dynamic.css?ver=1531211005.911
> 2. Clear the cache and check.